# Monitoring indexing size and identifying growth trends

Tags: lucene

I am using a commercial product (discovery tool) which has at its core Apache Lucene (v 3.6.1). I am about to ingest ~ 60K full-text along with metadata and I would like to get an idea of how the index size varies. Ideally, I would like to index bunches of 5/10K plain text each time and assess the index growth (I am expecting this to be linear).  My understanding is that the main file is .CFS (compound file), but I only seem to have the following formats:

```
.FDT (field index)
.FDX (field data)
.FNM (fields)
.FRQ (frequencies)
.NRM (norms)
.PRX (positions)
.TII (term info index)
.TIS (term infos)
.segment.GEN and segment_N (segments)
```

(I have read the file.CFS became optional from version 3.0.3, correct me if I am wrong). What would be the recommended approach? Any advice is more than welcome!

Thanks indeed,

I.

Comment: Each of those would be of interest in gauging index size.  All of them except the segments files are combined in the optional `.cfs` files.  While some will certainly impact size more than others, to get a complete picture of index growth, you would want to monitor all of them, or more to the point, the entire index directory.  Beyond that, really not sure what you are asking.

Comment: @femtoRgon, thanks for this, much appreciated. It was pretty much what I was looking for, I guess I will treat each of the files individually and monitor how they increase in size. Although, I am still interested to hear some best practices on this topic (e.g. statistical approaches that can be used).